# Proof that a $L^2$ function space defined on the reals is closed under addition

Tags: inner-products

Here's my attempt:

$$L^2$$ is closed under addition.
I need to show that
$$ \left(\int_a^b |f(t)|^2 \, dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\infty$$ and  $$\left(\int_a^b |g(t)|^2 \, dt \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\infty$$
then  $$\left(\int_a^b |f(t)+g(t)|^2 \, dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\infty$$

Invoking the Cauchy-schwartz inequality, we have:
$$\left \| f+g \right \|_{2}^{2} = \left \langle f+g,f+g \right \rangle = \left \langle f,f \right \rangle+\left \langle g,g \right \rangle +\left \langle f,g \right \rangle+\left \langle g,f \right \rangle = \left \| f \right \|_{2}^{2}+\left \| g \right \|_{2}^{2}+2Re\left \langle f,g \right \rangle \leq \left \| f \right \|_{2}^{2} + \left \| g \right \|_{2}^{2}+2\left \| f \right \|_{2}\left \| g \right \|_{2}$$

Could someone give me a little push?

Comment: Why do you include \left and \right in $\left| f(t)+g(t)\right|$ where they have no effect but omit them from the parentheses so that you see $\displaystyle ( \int_a^b\cdots\cdots )^{1/2}$ instead of $\displaystyle \left( \int_a^b \cdots\cdots \right)^{1/2}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I apologise. It gets pretty messy with the script. Will be more careful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $$\|f\|_2^2 + \|g\|_2^2 + 2\|f\|_2 \|g\|_2 = (\|f\|_2 + \|g\|_2)^2,$$

so you have $\|f + g\|_2^2 \le (\|f\|_2 + \|g\|_2)^2$. Now take square roots.

Comment: It was helpful. I would like to go on a tangent and ask what is the significance of the superscript '2' on L? I have tried to nail this down for a while but unable to arrive at a conclusion. I understand this 2 to be p=2 but what is this 2 associated with? Is this associated with the p-Norm where p=2?

Comment: No I don't mean 2 as a subscript but a superscript; 
$$L^{2}$$
In general, this is $$L^{p}$$ but where p=2 we have a function space of square integrable.
But is this $$L^{p=2}$$ necessarily associated with the p-Norm? 
Suppose we have a p-Norm where p =2, must the p-Norm where p=2 be necessarily defined on the function space of $$L^{p=2}$$?

Comment: The space $L^2$  consists of measurable functions $f$ for which $\|f\|_2 < \infty$. So yes, it's associated with the $2$-norm. In general, $L^p$ consists of those $f$ for which $\|f\|_p < \infty$.

Comment: Necessarily associated? Is it possible for it to be otherwise?

Comment: Yes, necessarily. It's not a matter of possibility, but of definition.

Comment: Thank you! It has been bothering me for so many weeks!